# "Self-satisfied" VS "Smug"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

As you can see in the definitions of the Cambridge Dictionary, the two words below are not distinguishable from one another. I was wondering if you could let me know if there is any nuance between them:

**[Self-satisfied](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/self-satisfied)**: (Adj.)

- Very pleased with yourself and showingno criticism of yourself:

**[Smug](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/smug)**: (Adj.)

- Too pleased or satisfied about something you have achieved or something you know.

If there is no difference, then I wonder why [Cambridge](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/self-satisfied) has brought them up both in the same example:

- > She was very **smug** and **self-satisfied** about getting the promotion.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that "smug" and "self-satisfied" do essentially mean the same thing.

Obviously, nobody but the author of that particular example in the dictionary can explain the reasoning behind their choice to use both. However, I can tell you that it isn't unusual to use a pair of synonyms in the same sentence, sometimes for emphasis.

For example "snug and warm" seems a fairly common expression, yet arguably the two adjectives are synonymous. "Raise up" or "absolutely essential" are two other common *redundancies*.

Some writers/speakers try hard to avoid redundancies in speech, but especially in creative writing, it is perhaps more common to use more adjectives than necessary, especially when words have an onomatopeia or conjure some imagery in the mind of the reader.

Comment: This would be especially true in a dictionary example sentence. Think about it; if a reader had no idea what _self-satisfied_ was, an example sentence such as: _She was very self-satisfied about getting the promotion_ may not help the reader gain much insight into the word's meaning. By pairing the word up with a synonym for emphasis, though, it's easier to get a better picture of what the word in question means.

Comment: I'm not sure many *competent* writers would seek to avoid the "redundancy" of using both ***smug*** and ***self-satisfied*** in proximity. As a general principle, excess verbiage is unwanted, but I'd say that with this particular pair it's a perfectly natural way of providing ***emphasis***. But I certainly find [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smug+complacency%2Cself-satisfied+complacency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmug%20complacency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cself%20-%20satisfied%20complacency%3B%2Cc0) interesting...

Comment: ...which I think shows how enthusiastically soldiers adopted the relatively uncommon (but slightly "quirky", and thus *easy to remember*) word ***smug*** when different linguistic communities were exposed to each other in the context of both WW1 and WW2.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Definitely interesting ngram! "Complacent" certainly has *more* meaning than "smug" - it implies that the smugness is *misplaced*, but as it *encompasses* smugness, it is a redundancy of sorts. Like my example, "snug and warm", as "snug" means more than just warm, but encompasses it.

Answer (score -2):

There is a difference, it's in even in the definition you have for smug, "too pleased or satisfied". In other words, you cross a line with your self-satisfaction. It is not always a bright line, but there is a point where other people get annoyed with you or your expression.

Comment: I don't think there's any meaningful difference. In practice, ***self-satisfied*** is almost always used negatively today, so it's effectively equivalent to ***too** self-satisfied* (i.e. - ***smug***).

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the OP quotes one dictionary definition and you are quoting another. Clearly, the words carry a broader meaning than is contained in a single definition.

Comment: @Astralbee *Too pleased or satisfied* is from the definition quoted in the question. Where do you see something different that's being quoted?